# split one string column to multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'scene':[{"living":"0.515","kitchen":"0.297"}, {"kitchen":"0.401","study":"0.005"}, {"study":"0.913"}, {}, {"others":"0"}], 'id':[1, 2, 3 ,4, 5]}) 

id        scene
01      {"living":"0.515","kitchen":"0.297"}
02      {"kitchen":"0.401","study":"0.005"}
03      {"study":"0.913"}
04      {}
05      {"others":"0"}
```

and I want to create a new dataframe as shown below, can someone help me to create this using Pandas?

```
id      living     kitchen     study     others
01      0.515       0.297        0         0 
02        0         0.401      0.005       0
03        0           0        0.913       0
04        0           0          0         0 
05        0           0          0         0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your data,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'scene':[{"living":"0.515","kitchen":"0.297"}, {"kitchen":"0.401","study":"0.005"}, 
                        {"study":"0.913"}, {}, {"others":"0"}], 
               'id':[1, 2, 3 ,4,5], 's': ['a','b','c','d','e']})

df:
    id  s   scene
0   1   a   {'kitchen': '0.297', 'living': '0.515'}
1   2   b   {'kitchen': '0.401', 'study': '0.005'}
2   3   c   {'study': '0.913'}
3   4   d   {}
4   5   e   {'others': '0'}
```

There are two ways you can go about doing this,

1. In a single line, where you have to input all column names except 'scene' to `set_index` function

   ```
   df = df.set_index(['id', 's'])['scene'].apply(pd.Series).fillna(0).reset_index()
   ```

   which will output:

   ```
      id   s   kitchen living  study   others
   0   1   a   0.297   0.515   0       0
   1   2   b   0.401   0       0.005   0
   2   3   c   0       0       0.913   0
   3   4   d   0       0       0       0
   4   5   e   0       0       0       0
   ```
2. In two lines, where you create your excepted result and concat it to the original dataframe.

   ```
   df1 = df.scene.apply(pd.Series).fillna(0)
   df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
   ```

   which gives,

   ```
      id   s                                    scene  kitchen living  study others
   0   1   a   {'kitchen': '0.297', 'living': '0.515'} 0.297   0.515   0     0
   1   2   b    {'kitchen': '0.401', 'study': '0.005'} 0.401   0    0.005    0
   2   3   c                        {'study': '0.913'} 0       0   0.913     0
   3   4   d                                        {} 0       0      0      0
   4   5   e                           {'others': '0'} 0       0      0      0
   ```

Comment: thanks. but what i want to do is not just fillna but also transform JSON style dataframe to as you mentioned above.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Your original dataframe is the first one and you want to transform it to the second one, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly i want transform first one to second one.

Comment: and my answer doesn't transform the first to second?

Comment: sorry nope. need to import json and use a list of dictionaries.

Comment: did you try with your method and succed?

Comment: There was a typo in my answer (`df.series`). Try this one.

Comment: Thanks. It works for test data, but doesn't for real data, maybe because my data have string type other columns as follows. df = pd.DataFrame({'scene':[{"living":"0.515","kitchen":"0.297"}, {"kitchen":"0.401","study":"0.005"}, {"study":"0.913"}, {}, {"others":"0"}], 'id':[1, 2, 3 ,4,5], 's':['a','b','c','d','e']})

Comment: @ahbon for that do `df.set_index(['id', 's'])....`.  You just have to input all the columns except the 'scene' in `set_index`.

Comment: It's weird your approach works with example data but not for my actual data. Can i send you my test data to have a try?

Comment: Yes. Please do.

Comment: Maybe because in actual data df.scene is json type and need to json.loads(scene), i'm not sure. But it didn't split to multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks. Send you by email?

Comment: Sure. Where do I share my email?

Comment: I share with dropbox the test data, please have a try. Sincere thanks.

Comment: @ahbon Well I tried on a sample of your shared data and my method is working. Can you share your error which you get instead?

Comment: Please check the columns of final dataframe, here is what i got: [ 'HouseId',      'AgentId', 'PhotoId', 'Image_Type', 'Img_Type', 'Scene', 'Scene_Review',      'Success', 0]

Comment: First approach code i use: df1 = df.Scene.apply(pd.Series).fillna(0)
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1) df2.columns

Comment: Second approach code i use: df2 = df.set_index(['HouseId', 'AgentId', 'PhotoId', 'Image_Type', 'Img_Type', 'Scene_Review', 'Success'])['Scene'].apply(pd.Series).fillna(0).reset_index()      df2.columns

Comment: df = pd.read_excel('/Users/x/Desktop/test.xlsx', index_col=None)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178724/discussion-between-raunaq-jain-and-ahbon).

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution is to convert your `scene` column to the list of dictionaries and create new data frame with default constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.scene.tolist()).fillna(0)
```

Result:

```
  kitchen living others  study
0   0.297  0.515      0      0
1   0.401      0      0  0.005
2       0      0      0  0.913
3       0      0      0      0
4       0      0      0      0
```

One of the "default" way to create DataFrame is to use a list of dictionaries. In this case each dictionary of list will be converted to the separate row and each key of dict will be used for the column heading.

Comment: you mean the method below?

Answer (score 0):

Updated. This one works perfectly. Welcome to give your suggestions to keep it more concise.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'scene':[{"living":"0.515","kitchen":"0.297"}, {"kitchen":"0.401","study":"0.005"}, {"study":"0.913"}, {}, {"others":"0"}], 'id':[1, 2, 3 ,4,5], 's':['a','b','c','d','e']}) 
def test(Scene, type):
    Scene = json.loads(Scene)
    if type in Scene.keys():
        return Scene[type]
    else:
        return ""

a = ['living', 'kitchen', 'study', 'others']
for b in a:
    df[b] = df['Scene'].map(lambda Scene: test(Scene, b.lower()))

cols = ['living', 'kitchen', 'study', 'others']
df[cols] = df[cols].replace({'': 0})
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The perfect one line solution is here, thanks for all helps:

```
df.join(df['scene'].apply(json.loads).apply(pd.Series))
```